# Multiple substring replace on ONE string (Tweets fed from API)

Tags: php, string, twitter, replace

I'm handling a bunch of Tweets in a PHP-application.
Replacing hashtags with links using regex is simple, but as for most suggested regular expressions for Twitter hashtags, these regex are just TOO simple. Trying to include non-ASCII letters, check for URL, etc., I realised that Twitter API returns "entities" with all this already handled for you.

The following example is a snippet for a Tweet with the hashtags `#something` and `#else`, with the string position (indices) for these.

```
["entities"]=>
  object(stdClass)#89 (4) {
    ["hashtags"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#90 (2) {
        ["text"]=>
        string(12) "something"
        ["indices"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          int(110)
          [1]=>
          int(123)
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#91 (2) {
        ["text"]=>
        string(7) "else"
        ["indices"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          int(126)
          [1]=>
          int(134)
        }
      }
    }
```

I just can't think of a good and effective solution to use this data to replace the hashtags on the source string. It's gotta be possible?

Naturally I know about `substr_replace`, but after making the first replacement, the string position will no longer match for the next replacement.

Might be able to calculate new positions after each replace, but that's when I thought I'd ask your opinion.

Comment: I just cant see the problem in using a simple regex...

Comment: @CarlosCarucce, I tend to agree with you, but here is a simple regex: `/(^|\s)#([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)(\s|$)/` that doesn't work with unicode characters (åö) to begin with, and then it breaks on hastags such as `!#hashtag` or `#hashtag...` and to fix that you have to be aware not to include this hashtag: `http://somelinkexample.com/#more`. It starts to get complex and is prone to changes on Twitter's end. And then you can repeat for usernames/mentions and links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Options i could think of:

1.) Use a offset to fix the difference: 
(verbal code)

```
$offset = 0;
while (hashtagToReplace){
   substr_replace($hashtagPosition + $offset, $htmlOfHashtag)
   $offset -= $length_of_replaced_word;
   $offset += $length_of_inserted_html;
}
```

2.) or the more simple way: Replace backwards, so that changing the "later" word does not affect the position of the words which are ahead in the original text. (`n to 0` rather than `0 to n`) (Inserting 1000 characters at position 126 first, does not change the position for 110)

Comment: Your solution 1 was what I was thinking of myself, but obviously I should have thought of replacing backwards, d'uh. Thanks.